# app_webview and code_cache folders auto generated in external storage

Tags: android, webview

My project is running fine but it's generating some folders which make it take more space than even the `apk` itself. The first folder as in the question I understand is from my `webview` and despite setting the `webview` not to store any cache, it still does that.

The second one however, I don't know where its coming from. I'll post my `webview` code but as for the other on, please tell me where it could be coming from. I'll also post my `build.gradle` in case it's a library doing that.

Here's my `webview`:

```
web.loadUrl(selectedProduct.url);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    web.clearCache(true);
```

Here is my `gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kamble.e_nunua"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "A"
      testInstrumentationRunner"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.toe.chowder:chowder:0.7.6'
implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'}
```

Comment: Did you find a fix?